# how to manage the back button on smartphone with alertdialog in my app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I would properly handle the pressure of the back button on your smartphone, I know That when is pressed displays an alertdialog That Asks, "Are you sure you want to quit by the APP" and if the users press again the app closes

Answer (score 2):

Overide the following method in the first Activity or the Activity where there is no return (except exit) of your application and show popup dialog to confirm the exit

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            YourActivity.this.finish();
        }
    };
    AlertDialog.Builder bldr = new Builder(YourActivity.this);
    bldr.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");
    bldr.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, listener);
    bldr.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null);
    bldr.show();
}
```

Comment: what error? did you replace **YourActivity** with your activity's name? and did you also fixed the *Imports* (if needed)?

Comment: yes, i Replaced "YourActivity" with the activity my name, and fixed with the imports. the error is here public void onBackPressed() {
      DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

Comment: change `new OnClickListener` to `new DialogInterface.OnClickListener`. Alternatively you may fix your imports by pressing **Ctrl+Shift+O**

Comment: I don't understand  where mistake but still does not work. :-(

Comment: Check [this](http://www.filedropper.com/helloworld) project in which i'm showing exit popup